# Mixed content error over https using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

When I tested the code over https protocol (heroku), the console simply fires the following messages:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/index.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost:5000/sockjs-node/info?t=1468848429270'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

The strange part is the code works fine when using over localhost.

**webpack.config.production.js**

entry: [
    './src/main'
  ],

**webpack.config.js**

entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://' + require("os").hostname() + ':5000/',
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    './src/main'
  ],

Is there any solutions about it?

Comment: If you are using HTTPS then everything should be HTTPS (secure) is expected, mixed content not allowed or you can use purely http that will work fine!

Comment: @NitinDhomse Yeah I'm loading everything via https, but it seems that the problem is caused by webpack dev server...

Comment: Why do you think this is related to webpack? Presumably you just have `http://localhost:5000` hardcoded somewhere, maybe a line like `var sock = new SockJS('http://localhost:5000/sockjs-node');`?

Comment: Make your server url https

Comment: @NitinDhomse The heroku server already running on https protocol, right?

Comment: Oh, it turns out the webpack dev server uses SockJS under the hood, so it is indeed possible (likely, unless your app uses SockJS elsewhere) that the two are related.

Comment: Perhaps it's as simple as changing `http` to `https` in `webpack.config.js`. I admit I don't understand what's going on here, so maybe that suggestion makes no sense. (You're running on Heroku but talking to `localhost`?)